# Spring transaction not setting connection readOnly false

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a setup where I use OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter to enable non-transactional reads from my database. In order to send those reads to a slave in a master/slave setup I set my connection pool to set connections to read-only by default. My problem is now that even tho methods annotated with @Transactional are read-write, the connection is not set to read-write and the transaction is sent to a read-only server. Is this the expected behaviour in Spring and/or how can I fix this?

Comment: we use a special annotation to switch between datasources : master / slave for situations like this, and read only attribute on transactional annotation, we don't do defaults on a pool though it's possible say for slave datasource

Comment: How did you set the connection pool to 'read-only' and what txn isolation is used?

Comment: @sura2k HikariCP has a HikariDataSource.setReadOnly and I´m using the default isolation level for innodb (repeatable read).

Comment: @borowis: J/Connctor and mariadb mysql client for java has a ReplicatorDriver that automatically chooses master/slace depending on the connection readOnly flag so I´m trying to use that since that is what it´s there for.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue although I have set the read-only flag to true by default in the CP30 pool. you can do this by ConnectionCustomizer interface.

I guess the spring assumes that the default read-only value to be false, hence makes no changes to it. See DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction

Dont know if this should be raised as a bug.